# How do I install serviio 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: server, software-installation, media, mediaserver

I have created a new user: serviio on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have downloaded the serviio package.

http://serviio.org/download

I would like to connect my music, pictures and movies from my PC to my Sony Bravia using the renderer system.

I have found some installation tips but only for serviio 1.0 or serviio 1.1.
I'm looking for recent tips and scripts and  clear how to change the files and add the scripts (because I'm a newbie). Do I need to install other programs like  mediatomb???

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Other media servers are not needed. Here is the [link](http://www.linuxmediaserver.net/digital-media/ubuntu-serviio/) to step by step guide on how to install Serviio 1.4 on Ubuntu 12.04.It may be useful for someone else just starting with this installation.

The summary of the involved steps for installing Serviio 1.4:

1. You need to install the Serviio pre-requisites:
   a. Install the building environment for the packages
   b. Build & install video codecs (including X264, Yasm, libvpx)
   c. Build & install FFmpeg  with the specific audio and video codecs support
2. Build and install Serviio

The detailed instructions for each step are provided in the link above.

Cheers,
Tomas

Comment: Link answers are not recommended, the linked site may go dead or unavailable. It would be better if you included the steps here too.